# Why inputs are not working in android webView after changing the language of the device?

Tags: reactjs, webview

I have android app with webview, developed with reactjs and i have below problem.

I open the app wait for complete loading.
went to android settings and changed language of the device.
Open the app from resents.
Now i am not able to enter any thing input fields.

But: If i kill the app and reopen it will work fine.

what might be the reason for the this?

How to solve it? because i have multi locale support.

Note:I am using Material input